# Java scanner issue - input mismatch

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

How do you separately scan a int and a letter most efficiently in Java? For example scan `"6L"` and save `6` as an `int` and register `L`.

Comment: If you tried implementing it please post your code also.

Answer (score 0):

Example code would have helped, as Stack Overflow is generally meant for debugging, it isn't really a programming tutorial forum. However, it's a good question, so here's what I suggest to you for any complicated analysis of text.

If you're already using something retro like a scanner, scan a `String` containing your textual representation. Once you have the String, use regular expressions.

In your case, that would be something like this:

```
String sz = scanner.next();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\w+)");  //meaning some number
// of digits, immediately followed by some number of word characters
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sz);

int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
String letters = matcher.group(1);
```

And there you have it (though note that that particular expression does not understand decimal points, you would have to modify it.)

You can find a complete explanation of regular expressions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and a handy site for testing them out [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). I hope that solves your problem. Good luck!